# Column Buckling: Which is more useful to plot; Buckling Load vs Slender Ratio, or, Stress vs Slender Ratio

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-engineering, materials, structures, mechanical-failure

Both have a linear relationship, is there any merit in plotting one over the other?

Comment: What do you mean by "stress vs Ratio"? The general description of stress in a member or the specific "buckling stress"? Please [edit] your question to clarify.